# Would you feel inertial forces if you were inside a precessing gyroscope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, gyroscopes

If a gyroscope is placed orthogonality on an physical axis which is paralel to a gravitational field if you're in a reference frame of the gyroscope do you have to modify Newton's law?